# How to get url with image with ios ShareExtension at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I want to share image URL with main homepage URL when sharing in safari to my iOS app with ShareExtension.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PqK2.jpg)

Currently, I am only getting an image URL.

Is this possible to get a homepage URL with an image URL with ShareExtension?

[Edit]

Actually, I am using https://github.com/meedan/react-native-share-menu in React Native.

I've also gone through the ShareExtension doc in iOS but it seems that it checks the share type and sends image URL only for the intent. Code is all there in the GitHub and you may test it out with the `Test` project in Github.

I am just wondering if there is any way to get a homepage URL with an image URL when sharing the image. Because the system is easy to know the homepage url while sharing an image URL.

Comment: Please add a code snippet of what you have.

Comment: @p-syche Just edited the question.